# SSIS Execute SQL Task needs to ignore error on DROP TABLE

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016

I am just getting started in SSIS for SQL Server 2016. I am trying to simply DROP TABLE before I create a new one, and I am using an Execute SQL Task as a first step before the Data Flow task to create the new table. I am getting an error that the object does not exist. It seems like this would be a very common thing to do in SSIS, and I have been reading through many SO posts on this particular task, but so far nothing on how to ignore an error. I was expecting to see a property for Execute SQL that allows ignoring errors, or an error connector, or something similar. Is there something in this task I missed, or is this the wrong way to make sure a table does not exist before trying to create a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `drop if exists` syntax inside EXECUTE SQL task:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tab_name; -- supported starting from SQL Server 2016
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, Change the Control Flow Arrow from Success to Completion:

1. Right Click the Green Arrow coming **from** the Execute T-SQL Task that drops the table.
2. Click Completion. Arrow will turn to black.